# ¿Como obtener la dirección de un elemento en un arreglo?

Tags: c++

El enunciado de mi problema es:

> Haga un programa en c++ que lea un arreglo tipo char y muestre en pantalla la
> dirección de las vocales.
>
> Ejemplo:
>
> "Holaa mundo"
>
> Vocal "o" en posicion 1,
>
> vocal "a" en posición 3, 4.
>
> ETC.
>
> Nota: no usar string.h.

*Cuando trato de imprimir la direccion de la vocal, muestra numeros
incorrectos. ¿me pueden sugerir algo?*

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

char *p,frase[50];
void entrada_datos();
void salida_datos();
int main(){
      entrada_datos();
    salida_datos();
    return 0;
}
void entrada_datos(){
    cout<<"Escriba una frase... "<<endl;
    cin.getline(frase,50);
}
void salida_datos(){
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        p=&frase[i];
        switch(*p){
            case'a':
                cout<<"\nVocal a en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
            case'e':
                cout<<"\nVocal e en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
            case'i':
                cout<<"\nVocal i en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
            case'o':
                cout<<"\nVocal o en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
            case'u':
                cout<<"\nVocal u en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
        }
    }

    cout<<"\nSu Frase : "<<frase;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en el switch:

```
switch(*p){
    case'a':
        cout<<"\nVocal a en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
    case'e':
        cout<<"\nVocal e en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
    case'i':
        cout<<"\nVocal i en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
    case'o':
        cout<<"\nVocal o en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
    case'u':
        cout<<"\nVocal u en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
}
```

Cuando compilas el código con las advertencias activadas sale esto:

```
main.cpp:31:58: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
             cout << "\nVocal o en posicion [ " << i << " ]";
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

De lo que advierte el compilador es que, una vez que el switch seleccione un caso
dependiendo del valor de la expresión (en este caso `*p`), la ejecución va a continuar
hasta que llegue al fin del switch si no hacemos que pare explicitamente con un break.

Por ejemplo, si `*p` es `'i'` entonces el switch es equivalente a:

```
cout<<"\nVocal i en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
cout<<"\nVocal o en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
cout<<"\nVocal u en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
```

Eso se soluciona agregando un break antes de que empieze cada case, de esta forma:

```
switch(*p){
    case'a':
        cout<<"\nVocal a en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
        break;
    case'e':
        cout<<"\nVocal e en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
        break;
    case'i':
        cout<<"\nVocal i en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
        break;
    case'o':
        cout<<"\nVocal o en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
        break;
    case'u':
        cout<<"\nVocal u en posicion [ "<<i<<" ]";
        break;
}
```